# How to raise exception, send it as a parameter to another method, and rescue the exception in the other method?

Tags: ruby

I have two methods as shown below, one tries to make a connection, if it fails
it raises an exception. That exception should then be rescued by another method,
who has been called by the method who raised the exception.

Currently the `conn` method raises the error, breaks the application and it's
never rescued. How do I rescue the exception, and is it possible to send the 
exception as the response parameter?

```
def conn
  begin 
    reponse = parse_response(
      conn.post(
        ..
      ).tap do |res|
        unless res.status == 200
          raise Error::AuthenticationError.new
        end
      end
    )
    ..
  end
end

def parse_response(response)
  body = 
    begin
      JSON.parse(response.body)
    rescue JSON::ParseError
    end
  rescue Error::AuthenticationError => e
    LOGGER.error e
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because of this part of your code executes before `parse_respose` method, as if it was written like this::

```rb
def conn
  begin
    response = conn.post(
        ..
      ).tap do |res|
        unless res.status == 200
          raise Error::AuthenticationError.new
        end
      end
    parse_response(response)
  end
end
```

You can move the rescue block to `conn` method:

```rb
def conn
  begin 
    reponse = parse_response(
      conn.post(
        ..
      ).tap do |res|
        unless res.status == 200
          raise Error::AuthenticationError.new
        end
      end
    )
    ..
  rescue Error::AuthenticationError => e
    LOGGER.error e
  end
end

def parse_response(response)
  body = 
    begin
      JSON.parse(response.body)
    rescue JSON::ParseError
    end
end
```

You can pass `conn.post` thing as a block to `parse_response` method or create a `Proc` or `lambda` object and pass it as a parameter. But I believe that better to deal with `Error::AuthenticationError` inside `conn` method.

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

You can pass exceptions around with some refactoring, but I'm taking the approach here of looking at passing exceptions as an anti-pattern for *expected* (but not necessarily *desirable*) results. If you really need the overhead of passing around exceptions, other answers will likely give you suggestions about how to do so through closures or refactoring your call stack.

### Analysis and Recommendations

There are certainly ways to pass exceptions around, but there's a bigger problem here, and that's the use of an exception to handle a non-exceptional use case. Exceptions should be...well, *exceptional*. An HTTP call that returns a non-200 status code is usually not a completely unexpected result. In fact, your code specifically checks for this state of affairs, so it's actually an *expected* code path in your application.

However, note that checking for "not 200 OK" isn't really the same as explictly checking for a 401 Unauthorized. In such cases, treating an expected condition as such is generally faster and less error prone than raising or passing around exceptions.

One way to approach this (but certainly not the only way) is to refactor your application to handle different *expected* outcomes sensibly. For example:

```
def conn
  response = conn.post

  # Pass through 200; handle everything else.
  case response.status
  when 200
  when 401 then handle_auth_error(response)
  when 403 then handle_forbidden_error(response)
  else raise "unexpected HTTP status code: #{response.status}"
  end

  parse_response(response)
end
```

The point of doing this is less about embedding the logic into #conn; it may certainly be worth extracting it to another method. The point is that you should be leaving exceptions for *unanticipated/uncaught errors* that can't be handled within the running application.

In this example, we only raise an exception on status codes we didn't anticipate. This leads to a much simpler solution, and likely a more robust application.